# AdSense block not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, google-adsense, ajax

I have copied and pasted the following code [into my page](http://southasianlitfest.com/2011/10/our-lady-of-alice-bhatti/), but it seems to be having no effect. It should have a fall back block colour, but nothing is showing.

Code copied/pasted straight from Google:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7972043490779920";
/* SALF */
google_ad_slot = "4085311300";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing your jQuery tweet js file which is causing a JavaScript error. Try fixing that to see if that is causing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, sometimes it just take about 10 minutes for adsense to display ads, IF you are running ads for the first time on that website .

also in some cases you must have some keywords for adsense to display relevant ads .

and in some other cases, for exemple if your domain is an adult domain with some adult keywords in the domain name it will not show ads at all .

Answer (score 1):

I think is not content quality/relevancy problem, try to fix this JavaScript errors first:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is just the exact thing that you have mentioned but AdSense and won't appear unless you have an account and the website is approved list to show AdSense ads.

If you own the AdSense account, then kindly wait for few mins to get the ads appear.